# NoClassDefFoundError when starting with Eclipse, but works fine with Ant

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, osgi, noclassdeffounderror

I'm developing an OSGi component in Eclipse (Oracle JVM 1.8 on linux).
When I run the component via an Eclipse Runconfiguration with all required bundles, the following error comes up:

```
ErrorMessage: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun/awt/image/ByteInterleavedRaster
```

My component imports the compiled boofcv.core.image.ConvertBufferedImage class, which uses the sun.awt.image.ByteInterleavedRaster class. When I check the rt.jar package, it lists the ByteInterleavedRaster class.

When the component is deployed with ant, everything works perfectly fine.

Since I'm not too skilled with Java CLASSPATH/compiling/Ant I don't know which further information I should provide for you.

---

The manifest contains the required bundle.
org.boofcv contains ConvertBufferedImage, which can not find the ByteInterleavedRaster class. [redacted] is of course a placeholder.

```
    Manifest-Version: 1.0
    Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
    Bundle-Name: [redacted]
    Bundle-SymbolicName: [redacted];singleton:=true
    Bundle-Version: 1.0.0
    Require-Bundle: org.apache.activemq,
      [redacted],
      org.boofcv
    Bundle-Activator: [redacted]
    Bundle-ActivationPolicy: lazy
    Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.7
    Import-Package: org.osgi.framework
    Export-Package: [redacted]
    Bundle-ClassPath: .
```

Comment: Maybe something like the MANIFEST file would be helpful. Have you specified (in the manifest) that you are importing this class?

Comment: I added the MANIFEST and the information.

Comment: @Josch you can accept the the answer it resolved the problem, I saw it in your code ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default the sun.* packages are not available for bundles in an OSGi container. The reason is that they are not part of the standard Java API. They might not be available in other implementations (like IBM JDK)

You can specify the availability of the JDK packages in several ways:

- Creating a custom java profile (search for osgi.java.profile)
- Specifiy the list of packages with the org.osgi.framework.system.packages
- Specify additional packages with the org.osgi.framework.system.packages.extra environment variable

If you search for the second two environment variables, you will find much information about the topic.

Comment: The following variable is already set: <pre>org.osgi.framework.bootdelegation=sun.awt.image</pre>    . That should do the same, right?

Comment: Here is a good description: http://spring.io/blog/2009/01/19/exposing-the-boot-classpath-in-osgi/ . I would use system.packages.extra in your case. See the  "Which solution is better?" chapter to see why boot delegation should not be used in this case.